# Spring.Net IoC: alternative to using configuration metadata XML

Tags: ioc-container, spring.net

I'm trying to get a grasp of using spring.net ioc to suit my purpose.

What options to using xml configuration (metadata file) are available in spring.net ioc. i.e. i don't want to use the following:

```
<object name="MyMovieFinder"
    type="Spring.Examples.MovieFinder.SimpleMovieFinder, 
    Spring.Examples.MovieFinder"/>
</object>
```

Instead, i want to load this values from a database like below:

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ObjName, ObjType, ObjPath from tblApp", cn)
   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.read)
  IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
  MovieLister lister = (MovieLister) ctx.GetObject (dr["ObjName"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store your object definitions in a database and use that to power your application you should look at the IResource interface, there's a chapter on it in the Spring.NET documentation [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/resources.html).